# $\sum _{i=0}^n e^{i/n}$

Tags: calculus

It is a very basic question but I cant seem to find a intuitive way of thinking how to convert

$$\sum _{i=0}^n e^{i/n}$$

to closest form.

The answer should be:

$$\frac{e^{\frac{n+1}{n}}-1}{e^{1/n}-1}$$

And the sum. formula used:

$$\sum _{i=1}^n r^{i-1}=\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$$

The way I look at it is if i=j-1, thus when i=1 j=2, so im getting something like (i-2), but im pretty sure I am totally off and Im not able to get to the correct answer anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula can be written as $\sum_{i=0}^n r^i = \frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$. Apply it with $r=e^{1/n}$.
Then you get
$$ \frac{(e^{1/n})^{n+1}-1}{e^{1/n}-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

The kicker, here, is to notice that $$e^{i/n}=\left(e^{1/n}\right)^i$$ for all (real) numbers $i$. So, putting $r=e^{1/n},$ we see that the sum is in fact a geometric sum--namely $$\sum_{i=0}^ne^{i/n}=\sum_{i=0}^nr^i,$$ which has the closed form $$\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1},$$ since we know (why?) that $r\ne 1.$ At that point, you simply re-substitute for $r.$